# Can we say that for everything in our universe to exhibit a behaviour, it should have the capability to process information?v(details below)

Tags: thermodynamics, particle-physics, quantum-information, universe, data

Take the simple case of water molecules.. you freeze them, it turns into ice.. at around 100° it vaporizes.

For each and every reaction in this example, the molecule needs to react to heat, for it to react to heat, it needs to sense and validate heat. For it to sense and validate heat, it needs to process the information regarding its surroundings.

Same with everything else.. be it atoms or electrons.

Comment: I'm voting to close as this seems really an opinion based issue.  It depends entirely on what you consider "information" and "processing information" to mean.  I don't think these have well defined meanings in physics.

Comment: Information is information. How can you be confused on what it means ? It's data and understanding of data. Data regarding heat. This was a really good question but I don't know why some peoe just have to shut people off for a non typical question
 It's not even opinion based. It's about the core concepts of reaction. For you to react to something you need to sense it first. But nevermind. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What humans perceive as *heat* is the kinetic energy of molecules bumping into us. Molecule increases or decreases its kinetic energy by bumping against its surroundings - in order to participate in such a simple physical process, the molecule does not need to know anything about this process - in the sense how humans describe it. It is a kind of like a person getting hit by a truck - they need not realize what has happened to get wounded (though it would be nice, if we could control it.)